# Custom Histogram aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, histogram, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a index of following structure

```
item_id: unique item id
sale_date: date of the date
price: price of the sale wrt the date
```

I want to create a histogram of the latest sale prices per item. aggregate term `item_id` and histogram of last or latest `price`

My first choice was to `term` aggregate `item_id` and pick `price` from `top_hits` size 1 order `sale_date` `desc` and create histogram on the python end.

but.
since the data is in 10s of millions of records for one month. It is not viable to download all `sources` in time to perform histogram.

Note: Some item sell daily and some at different time interval. which makes it tricky to just pick latest `sale_date`

**Updated**:

**Input**: Item based sales time series data.

**Output**: Historgram of the count of items lies in a certain price buckets wrt to latest information

Answer (score 0):

I have turn around that I used similar case, You can use `max` aggs with `date` type, and you can `order` aggregation based on nested `aggs` value, to be like:

```
"aggs": {
  "item ID": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "item_id",
      "size": 10000
    },
    "aggs": {
      "price": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "price",
          "size": 1,
          "order": {
            "sale_date": "desc"
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "sale_date": {
            "max": {
              "field": "sale_date"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope that will help you, and I wish you inform me if it works with you.

Comment: I think you didnot understand the question. this is not the results i am expecting. the aim is a histogram aggregation from the `selling price` terms in x axis and count item_id s for y axis